# Scrolling on iPad becomes stuck

Tags: salesforce1-app, ipad, scrolling

I looked to see if there was a similar question on this site, but couldn't find one, and apologize if this is a repeat question.

My company is doing some front end work for a client building an app in SF1. One of the SF1 specific bugs I've run into lately is with scrolling on an iPad. Every so often the scrolling becomes "stuck" and replicates what happens when you reach the end of a page, despite there being more content above or below. If you tap it a few times it will eventually respond to the scrolling again. This does not happen all the time, and it pops up at completely random times. Has anyone experience this issue? I'm going insane trying to figure out what is causing it.

Comment: Have you turned off `showHeader` and `standardStylesheets` yet?

Comment: Yes - they're both set to false; I'm trying this solution next:

http://vukoje.net/post/Integrating-responsive-site-in-Salesforce1